# Windows Explorer hangs creating thumbnails for Typescript files

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Whenever I open a folder with many `.ts` (typescript) files, Windows Explorer hangs for several seconds attempting to generate thumbnails for each file. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `windows-explorer-fix-ts-files.reg` file with these contents ([or download it here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sparebytes/a88aa4c27174bc7007a4792051753694/raw/8219b0c53c51fe86ed9ce8bd000690e87f330984/windows-explorer-fix-ts-files.reg)) and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ts]
@="txtfile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="text"
```

*This is a just quicker version of [nytamin's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1464304/152766).*

Answer (score 14):

A system-wide solution is described here:

https://wizcorp.tumblr.com/post/176015676507/fix-inside-why-windows-explorer-goes-funky-in

> Open the registry editor, navigate to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.ts (tip: as you open regedit.exe, type Ctrl+L to focus the address bar, paste the path and then press enter), double click on the PerceivedType key and replace video by text.
>
> This will stop the madness for future folders. ... You may also dig further down and replace the `Content Type` and the `(Default)` keys to read `text/plain` and `txtfile` respectively

[image: screenshot of configuration]

Comment: I'm not sure but I think a restart is required after these changes.

Comment: Confirmed, this works after signing out and back in.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to edit your answer with a quicker version but it got rejected by some annoying moderator so I made a new one.

Comment: Killing the Explorer with the Taskmanager also does the job of reloading this setting.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the view of the folder to Details or List, which doesn't show custom thumbnails for each file. But if you can't get into the folder to set the view without Explorer hanging, just go to the folder's parent, right click the folder and go to `Properties`, go into the `Customize` tab, and change `Optimize this folder for` to either "General items" or "Documents". This should automatically present the contents of the folder (when you go into it) in Details or List view.

Comment: Thanks. This a decent solution although I'd rather have a system-wide solution. I have to do this fix on a case-by-case basis but it's not too bad as long as I keep all my projects in the same folder that I need apply this to.

Comment: Also, I still had this issue when I set my folder to Details/List view. I had to customize the folder as `Documents` to solve this.

Comment: Well, you could set the default folder template of your entire system to `Documents`, but that might be really annoying (depending on what sorts of other folders you have).

Comment: Another idea - and this is kind of weird, so it's up to you - is to set the default application for `.ts` files to a program that doesn't generate thumbnails at all, or doesn't know how to handle `.ts` files. (e.g.: my machine thinks `.ts` files are "Films & TV" files, so the icon is just the default video icon). I'm not sure what application you're using that's generating the thumbnails though, so I don't know if this will help at all.

Comment: I actually changed the default program but that didn't stop the thumbnails from being generated.

Comment: Even if you do this, you will have to do it for every folder. And even if you do it for every folder, if you hit F5 to refresh in a folder with a lot of `.ts` files, it seems to take several seconds trying to generate a thumbnail for each file, even in Details view. The answer by [Nytamin](https://superuser.com/a/1464304/1117) seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers didn't work for me (on Windows 10). All `.ts` or `.d.ts` files showed up as the `video` file kind in explorer. This is what causes Windows explorer to "scan" the files and makes opening folders containing `.ts` files slow.

[image]

To change the mapping of file extension to file kind, go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap` and set the `.ts` entry to `document`.

[image]

Then either reboot or if you're in a hurry start task manager and kill+restart `explorer.exe`.

This finally solved the problem for me!

You can instead create a `ts-kind-fix.reg` file with these contents and double-click it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap]
".ts"="document"
```

Helpful sources:

- More info about "file kinds" in Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/prophand-content-view
- [List files in folder that match kind](https://superuser.com/questions/1341778/list-files-in-folder-that-match-kind)
- https://wizcorp.tumblr.com/post/176015676507/fix-inside-why-windows-explorer-goes-funky-in
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/551eed27-6aaa-4ee2-8ab7-e843ae103c50/disable-file-contents-scanning-not-thumbnail-in-explorer-view-for-ts-files?forum=w7itproui

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on [Microsoft TechNet forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/551eed27-6aaa-4ee2-8ab7-e843ae103c50/disable-file-contents-scanning-not-thumbnail-in-explorer-view-for-ts-files?forum=w7itproui):

> Rename temporarily the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertyHandlers\.ts` and see if this helps.
>   Renamed .ts to .ts_disabled (so I can revert easily if needed) and it seems to work well.