# List files in folder that match kind

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-search

In Windows Search I can use `kind:=music OR  kind:=video` to get all results in a folder/ subfolders which are that type of media.

Is there a way to replicate this with a command like `dir` on the command line, or will I have to do some fancy manipulation with my exported *kind map* `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap` to get a list of file extensions to search against. Then do something like [this](https://superuser.com/a/318213/705597)

Ultimately I'm after a csv or equivalent with all files matching the search criteria

Answer (score 2):

First batch attempt working only halfway as findstr capitulates on the sheer number of extensions in Kinds documents,music,picture and video.

**EDIT 2nd working version with an (ugly) temporary file containing the Kinds extensions**

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\20\SU_1341778.cmd
:: DirKind.cmd music x:\path\folder
@Echo off

:: Possible Kind_ type strings
Set "Kinds=calendar communication contact document email link music picture"
Set "Kinds=%Kinds% playlist program recordedtv searchfolder video"

Echo=%Kinds%|Findstr /i "%~1" 2>&1>Nul ||(Echo invalid Kind:%1 &TimeOut 5&Exit /B 1)

Set "TempFile=%temp%\Kind_%~1.ext"
:: Build Kind_ string enumerating extensions
Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap"
( For /f "tokens=1,3" %%A in (
    'reg query "%Key%"^|find "%~1"'
  ) do Echo=%%A
) > "%TempFile%"

Echo Dir all files of Kind %1 in folder "%~2"
Call Set "Kind=%%Kind_%1%%"
For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B /A-d "%~2\*" ^| Findstr /i /E /G:"%TempFile%" '
) Do Echo %%A
```

Sample output

```
> Q:\Test\2018\07\20\SU_1341778.cmd link "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
Dir all files of Kind link in folder "C:\Users\LotPings\Desktop"
Access 2016.lnk
ClassicStartMenu.exe - Verknüpfung.lnk
Excel 2016.lnk
FreeCommander XE.lnk
Microsoft Edge.lnk
OneNote 2016.lnk
Outlook 2016.lnk
PowerPoint 2016.lnk
Publisher 2016.lnk
shutdown.exe.lnk
UltraVNC Server.lnk
UltraVNC Settings.lnk
UltraVNC Viewer.lnk
WinDirStat.lnk
Windows 10-Update-Assistent.lnk
Word 2016.lnk
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I'm looking for something specific in my directories I like this one liner

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path C:\Users\ -Include*.ext
```

so an example in your case would be

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path C:\Users\[Uname]\Downloads -Include *.mp3,*.mov; # etc
```

From the get-help text

```
-Path <String[]>
    Specifies a path to one or more locations. Wildcards are permitted. The default location is the current directory (.).

-Recurse [<SwitchParameter>]
    Indicates that this cmdlet gets the items in the specified locations and in all child items of the locations.

-Include <String[]>
    Specifies, as a string array, an item or items that this cmdlet includes in the operation. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as *.txt. Wildcards are permitted.

    The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory, such as C:\Windows\*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.
```

I'll run a search on a scripts folder looking for PowerShell and Bash files as an example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path .\Desktop\scripts\ -Include *.ps1,*.sh
```

Result:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\[user]\Desktop\scripts\Bash


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/22/2018   8:03 PM             84 runit.sh


    Directory: C:\Users\[user]\Desktop\scripts\PS


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        4/19/2018   9:04 PM            173 pass_d.ps1
-a----         9/7/2017   4:45 PM            345 refresh.ps1
-a----        5/11/2018   9:05 PM           1589 test.ps1
-a----        4/20/2018   8:55 PM            273 wifi_list.ps1
```

This won't take a `kind:=music,kind:=video` argument, but you can provide asterisks with file extensions as an array for the `-Include *.mp3,*.mov` argument and can search multiple directories similarly `-Path /some/directory,some/directory2`. 
Running that same one line command piped to `| Export-Csv [filename].csv` will save your results as a .csv file.

**Tip**: PowerShell has tab completion available so you don't have to type out every argument. `get-ch<tab>` > `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-ChildItem -i<tab>` > `Get-ChildItem -Include`, etc.