# How to prevent Windows Explorer from generating thumbnails for a specific folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbnails

I use rclone to mount a remote as a drive on Windows 10, however whenever I open a folder that contains videos, Windows Explorer starts trying to create thumbnails fo them which makes rclone re-download the files every time which eats up unnecessary bandwidth.

So I want to know how I can prevent Windows Explorer from doing this on the specific rclone mounted drive but not anywhere else.

Switching to "list" view on the folder doesn't stop it.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1304114/windows-explorer-hangs-creating-thumbnails-for-typescript-files

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed explanation for ways to do this [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2014/03/12/thumbnail-cache-files-windows/).

In short, open Explorer and navigate to the folder in question. Select **File** > **Change folder and search options**.

Select the **View** tab.

In the Files and Folders section, check **Always show icons, never thumbnails** to disable the generation of the database files.

Press **OK** to apply to the current folder only. (To apply to *all* folders, press  **Apply to Folders**).

[image]

Comment: Please read the dialog box carefully. You press 'OK' to apply to THIS FOLDER ONLY and press 'Apply to folders' to apply the view to ALL FOLDERS.

Comment: Ah, I did not know this, thanks for the tip, you should edit your answer to include hitting ok only applies it to the current folder.

Comment: OK - done. And would you be so kind as remove the down vote (if that was from you)?

Comment: Hitting okay does *not* apply this change only to the current folder. The advanced settings section apply to all folders, all the time, no matter what.